# Generate unique, random alphanumeric primary key of length 10

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, random

I want to use Hibernate to generate a unique primary key for an entity which is random - to use for purposes such as payment confirmation numbers, hotel room booking numbers, gift-card codes, etc. - any time a customer facing unique value is needed to identify an entity.

They should not be predictable by end users, but need not be cryptographically secure. The length must be 10 characters alphanumeric, using all capital letters.

There are a lot of similar questions, but none of them seem to actually solve the problem. I can't be the first one to have this issue.

I want to avoid the brute force method of just generating a random alphanumeric string and checking if it exists in the db or not.

Comment: If it's random, then by definition it's not guaranteed to be unique.  Is there a reason you have such a specific format requirement and thus can't use a GUID?

Comment: Because it's something the user might need to use to input into a field, for example, and the length would then be prohibitive. I don't necessarily need *random*, just non-predictable (or at least, not easily predictable. In other words, I don't want sequential integers in our database for order numbers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate 10-digit base-36 numbers. To make them unpredictable, instead of going one-by-one you can skip among them using any value that is relatively prime to 36^10.

For example:

```
public class Unique {
    private static final long SKIP = 1656158440062971L;
    private static final long MOD  = 3656158440062976L;
    private static final long BASE = 36L;

    public static class ExhaustedException extends RuntimeException {
        public ExhaustedException() { super("No more codes"); }
    }

    private long currentValue = 0L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int max = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        Unique generator = new Unique();
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            System.out.println(generator.nextCode());
        }
    }

    public synchronized String nextCode() {
        currentValue = (currentValue + SKIP) % MOD;
        if (currentValue == 0L) {
            throw new ExhaustedException();
        }
        return codeFromLong(currentValue);
    }

    private String codeFromLong(long value) {
        StringBuilder code = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int digit = (int) (value % BASE);
            code.insert(0, charFromDigit(digit));
            value /= BASE;
        }
        return code.toString();
    }

    private char charFromDigit(int digit) {
        if (digit < 10) return (char) ('0' + digit);
        return (char) ('A' + (digit - 10));
    }
}
```

This will generate 10-character alphanumeric codes in an apparently random order. It will repeat after 3,656,158,440,062,976 (3.6 quadrillion) codes. To prevent duplicates, before it would generate a 0 and then repeat it throws an `ExhaustedException`. It is guaranteed to visit each code once and only once because 1,656,158,440,062,971 is relatively prime to the total cycle length.

I generated this value by changing the first digit to a 1 and tweaking the final digit. It isn't important exactly what this number is, and it does not need to be a prime, but it must not share any common factors with 36^10 (must be relatively prime), and it should be large but not close to 36^10 so that most or all of the digits will change every time you turn the crank.

This is a self-contained program but you will probably want to put the current value into the database and perhaps even put this code behind a stored procedure, in which case you might want to have it return some distinct sentinel value to indicated the sequence has been exhausted. I have made the method that generates the next code `synchronized`; you need to ensure, one way or another, that no two callers receive the same code.

**Note: That means this could become a bottleneck in your app.**

I would also put a wrapper around it and check for a stoplist of expletives. You don't want to give a customer a code that contains a four-letter or other offensive word. If a code contains a bad word as a substring simply throw it away and generate the next code.

Comment: I know it's late but this is a great answer.

Comment: @Bassinator Better late than never! Thanks!